# Excel add-in needs to run automatically at workbook startup

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make an Excel add-in active/run at workbook startup....need code. The add-in with parameter is:  "OPCS7200ExcelAddin.XLA!StartOPC"

Have been given this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Call Excel.Application.Run("OPCS7200ExcelAddin.XLA!StartOPC")

End Sub
```

But this code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I've just got similar code to work on my machine (Excel 2003, XP).  Not knowing whether you get any error message, I could suggest the following I guess:

1) Ensure that you have the xla add-in loaded when your workbook goes to open.

2) Alternatively, add a reference to your XLA and call the code directly:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    OPCS72000ExcelAddin.StartOPC
End Sub
```

Regards,

Chris